# how to remove/skip the first two parts in the path javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I would like to know how to remove the first two parts in the url javascript.
how to show the path after secondpart of url in javascript

```
var arr =[
  "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\index.js",
  "D:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js",
  "E:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js"
]

function getAllPath(arr){
    const outputArr = arr.map(item => {
       return item.split("/").slice(3).join("/");
    });
    return outputArr
}

Expected Output
[
  "/dc/public/index.js",
  "/dc/public/javascripts/index1.js",
  "/dc/public/javascripts/index2.js",
]
```

Comment: The original paths contain backslashes, not forward slashes...

Comment: Seems like you want to use `.split("\\").slice(2).join("/");` instead?

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1: use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var arr =[
  "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\index.js",
  "D:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js",
  "E:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js"
]

function getAllPath(arr){
    const outputArr = arr.map(item => {
       return "/" + item.split("\\").slice(2).join("/");
    });
    return outputArr
}

console.log(getAllPath(arr));
```

### Method 2: use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var arr =[
  "C:\\Users\\dc\\public\\index.js",
  "D:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js",
  "E:\\Users\\dc\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js"
]

function getAllPath(arr){
    const outputArr = arr.map(item => {
       return item.replace(/^[A-Z]:\\Users\\/, "/").replace(/\\/g, "/");
    });
    return outputArr
}

console.log(getAllPath(arr));
```